# Jenkins Reverse proxy - Nginx

Tags: jenkins, nginx-reverse-proxy

I set up Jenkins on my mac and use Nginx as reverse proxy.
I follw the doc( https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/reverse-proxy-configuration-nginx/ ) but stuck on

Set the context path by modifying the jenkins.xml configuration file and adding --prefix=/jenkins to the  entry.

I can't find jenkins.xml in my folder (only config.xml)
[image]

[image]

And I don't know where to add --prefix=/jenkins, it only says add to the  entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can export this as an Environment variable as shown below before starting Jenkins. Or add this to the Jenkins startup script.

```
export JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/jenkins"
```